# Why do I get error when trying to parse this json object?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json, codeigniter

I have the following PHP (Codeigniter Frameword) code:

```
$webpages = $this->webpageModel->select('webpageID,webpageTitle')->where('webpagecategoryID', $webpagecategoryID)->findAll();
header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo json_encode(array("response" => $webpages))
```

In the console, this is what is displayed:

```
{"response":[{"webpageID":"3","webpageTitle":"\u03a7\u03b1\u03b9\u03c1\u03b5\u03c4\u03b9\u03c3\u03bc\u03cc\u03c2 \u03b1\u03c0\u03cc \u03c4\u03bf\u03bd \u03c0\u03c1\u03cc\u03b5\u03b4\u03c1\u03bf"}]}
```

This is my JavaScript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        let category = $('#webpagecategoryID');
        let webpage = $('#webpageID');
        category.on('change', function(e) {
            webpage.empty();
            var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
            req.open("GET", "<?php echo base_url(); ?>/backEnd/Ticker/webpages_from_selected_category/" + category.val(), false);
            req.send();
            let res = JSON.parse(req.response);
            let response = res.response;
            let len = Object.keys(response).length;
            for (let i = 0; i < len; i++) {
                let titleLength = 150;
                var trimmedTitle = response[i]['webpageTitle'].substring(0, titleLength);
                webpage.append("<option value=" + response[i]['webpageID'] + ">" + trimmedTitle + "</option>");
            }
        });
    });
```

In the Javascript, when I try to parse the object, I get an error: Uncaught SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected non-whitespace character after JSON data at line 2 column 1 of the JSON data

What I am doing wrong?

Comment: The JSON you've posted is valid. From the error it would appear that's not the same as what is being returned from your XMLHttpRequest, though, as it implies there's some invalid characters added in there. Check your PHP to ensure ONLY the JSON is returned, and also check the response in the network tab of the console.

Comment: Also, as you're using jQuery anyway, why not just use `$.ajax()` instead of XMLHttpRequest? Your code will be cleaner and more succinct.

Comment: I just wanted to re-use existing code, that was my idea.

Answer (score 0):

My problem has not been related with the JSON at all. I use CodeIgniter 4, which in the development environment post in the console the following tag:

```
<script type="text/javascript"  id="debugbar_loader" data-time="1611742634" src="http://ea3.test/index.php?debugbar"></script><script type="text/javascript"  id="debugbar_dynamic_script"></script><style type="text/css"  id="debugbar_dynamic_style"></style>
```

after my JSON. And after I switch the environment to production, this script tag is not displayed in the console, and my code works just fine.

Comment: So we could not reproduce this error then? Off-topic: Cannot reproduce.